# Handling mysql errors

Tags: php, logging

I am currently working on my site and have the following set up for most sql queries

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET column='$value'WHERE id='$id'"))
{ echo("error: " . mysqli_error($con)); }
```

Works fine, but on reflection i think its a bad idea to echo the error. I use this method multiple times across hundreds of files so im asking if there is an easy way to rectify this without having to go to each file manually and also the best way of logging the error.

Is it better to insert it into another table, text file, or just ignore it? If so, may i have an example of how to go about it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Maintain a `log` table for it or text file named as `error_log` or use `try` and `catch` structure for it. This is really a bad practice.

Comment: We can't tell you how do handle the logging of your errors since it all depends on how you deal with your websites and what are your options to recover and check them. It will therefore be about opinions. However, echoing the technical error output to the users isn't a wise option.

Comment: You know whats a really really really bad idea? To put variables into your querys like you did. I think they can be affected by userinputs? So your code is really vulnerable to SQL injections and your database can be hacked in a few seconds without and problems. Look at http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL injections and how to prevent them. They've really nice examples there on how to use prepared statements and on how to make your code safe. Right now I would never go productive with your code, its a really high risk.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you began to display the error manually, you will have to refactor each of your file manually. Also, if your end user is not a developer, displaying the exact database error is a huge security breach. Think of a general error like `an error occured while processing your request`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather you can use below function to put your error log:

```
error_log("Failed to connect to database!", 0);
```

EDIT

Take a look at the log_errors configuration option in php.ini. It seems to do just what you want to. I think you can use the error_log option to set your own logging file too.

When the log_errors directive is set to `On`, any errors reported by PHP would be logged to the server log or the file specified with error_log. You can set these options with `ini_set` too, if you need to.

(Please note that `display_errors` should be disabled in php.ini if this option is enabled)